# how to manually send Pong frames to websockets using akka

Tags: scala, websocket, akka

I have a websocket client written in scala-akka which is consuming a websocket server. That server is sending a `ping` every 3 minutes and expecting a `pong` . Pong frame messages can be sent unsolicited also.

However, akka supports Automatic keep-alive but only when the connection is idle. The connection is never idle but I want to send pong frames to the server otherwise the connection gets disconnected.

I have tried to pass a source like this

```
val pong = Source.tick(0 minute, 1 minute, BinaryMessage.apply(ByteString.apply("0xA")))
//or like this
val pong = Source.tick(0 minute, 1 minute, TextMessage.apply("pong"))
```

but they do not seem to work, the connection drops after 3 minutes, exactly as specified in the docs.

```
val flow = Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupledMat(printSink, pong)(Keep.both)
val (upgradeResponse, closed) = Http().singleWebSocketRequest(webSocketRequest, flow)
```

The part of the docs mentioning this:

```
The websocket server will send a ping frame every 3 minutes. If the websocket server does not receive a pong frame back from the connection within a 10 minute period, the connection will be disconnected. Unsolicited pong frames are allowed.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Akka HTTP will always responds to PING frames with PONG frames automatically. The documentations bits you cite are about whether pings (or unsolicited pongs) should be sent in addition to that which as you say may only happen when the connection is idle. So maybe something else is at play here?